# How to iterate over dynamic concatenated array without breaking excution flow of for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to append items dynamically to an array at run time and want to iterate them without breaking the flow of execution of the program;

**Question:** i want to dynamically add item to my [object of array] and continue the iteration without breaking the execution flow.

**Test cases to be kept in mind:**

1. my print should go 1 by one without braking the execution
2. next concatenated items should print in the next iteration only

```js
let contactMap = {0:['Array 0 1','Array 0 2','Array 0 3']};
let counter = 1;

function addDelay(time){
  return new Promise((res) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          res();
      },time * 5000);
  });
}

document.getElementById('concatMore').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  contactMap[counter++] = [`Array ${counter} 1`,`Array ${counter} 2`];
  //console.log(contactMap);
 iterateOverItems();
});


async function iterateOverItems(){
  for(var key in contactMap){
   if(key && contactMap[key]){
       for(let i = 0; i < contactMap[key].length; i++){
         await addDelay(i);
         console.log(`[Key]:${key}, item: ${contactMap[key][i]}`);
       }
     }
  }
}


iterateOverItems();
```

```html
<button id="concatMore">
  Concat More dynamically at run time without breaking execution flow.
</button>
```

**Note:** solution in vue is most welcomed !!

Comment: How is the "execution flow" broken? Explain exactly what results you expected and why, and how it compares to what you actually get.

Comment: @marekful when i click the button `Concat More dynamically at run time without breaking execution flow.` then it happens while running.

Comment: Note: solution in vue is most welcomed !!

Translation: Please do my job for me.

Comment: Here's a less confusing fiddle.  Your code does not "break execution flow" - the problem is that you're restarting `iterateOverItems` each time you add new ones, so your "flow" is running twice in parallel, skewing/confusing the results.   In this simple you can see that, once you start (just once) and concat multiple items during the flow, the original "flow" only iterates as if you had not added new items.  https://jsfiddle.net/aey5kL0f/1/  So your code already does exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's really not very clear what you ask since nothing seems broken (i.e. no errors), probably something around order... Either way, your approach is wrong. If you need to deal with promises in a loop, you should use Promise.all or similar.

Comment: @marekful looks like the "promise" is just the standard way to add a `sleep` function without using setTimeout